# Mysql left join store previous value if condition query correction

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement

When I perform left join from a derived table (a mapping table) using a variable @prevValue in if condition to store previous value, I get different results

Here are the tables

```
Table_1

Date                    Value
2020-03-02 00:00:00      0
2020-03-02 07:00:00      1
2020-03-02 12:00:00      0

Table_2
2020-03-02 00:00:00      0
2020-03-02 07:00:00      1
2020-03-02 12:00:00      1
2020-03-02 14:00:00      0
```

```
Mapping_table
Date
2020-03-02 00:00:00
2020-03-02 01:00:00
2020-03-02 02:00:00
2020-03-02 03:00:00
...
```

Here is my query (I even added counters to check how mysql joins the table)

```
SET @prevValue=0;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(P.date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `date`, 
IF(D.date IS NULL ,@prevValue, @prevValue:=D.value) AS `dataValue`
    FROM (SELECT `T`.`date` FROM `Mapping_table` AS `T`
     WHERE (date >= '2020-03-02 00:00:00') AND (date <= '2020-03-02 23:59:00')) AS `P`
LEFT JOIN `Table_1` AS `D` ON D.date=P.date ORDER BY `P`.`date` ASC;
```

Results to the following:

```
Date                    Val
---------------------------
"2020-03-02 00:00:00"   "0"
"2020-03-02 00:01:00"   \N
"2020-03-02 00:02:00"   \N
"2020-03-02 00:03:00"   \N
"2020-03-02 00:04:00"   \N
"2020-03-02 00:05:00"   \N
```

Querying to Table_2 (I just replaced the query with Table_2) yields the following:

```
Date                    Val
---------------------------
"2020-03-02 00:00:00"   "0"
"2020-03-02 00:01:00"   "0"
"2020-03-02 00:02:00"   "0"
"2020-03-02 00:03:00"   "0"
"2020-03-02 00:04:00"   "0"
"2020-03-02 00:05:00"   "0"
```

My desired result with be the last one. I expect the left join from Table_1 should return the same as Table_2 result? Do you guys have an idea what should I change in my query or explain why this happens?

Mysql version used 5.7

Comment: The results look the same to me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6GdJFZG4RCUP57twWFcbfR/1

Comment: If you use user-defined variable then the query must be single-source with ordering by unique expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little long for a comment.

In MySQL 8+, variables in `SELECT` are deprecated . . . and for good reason.  There are superior methods to do what you want.

I'm pretty sure the issue is the ordering.  You want the variables to be evaluated *after* `ORDER BY`.  Alas, I recall that this changed in the later versions of MySQL 5.x.

So, the solution to your problem is to use a subquery with an `ORDER BY` to get the rows in the order that you want.  MySQL materialized such subqueries so the ordering is "fixed" (although I don't like to depend on that ;).  Then use the variables in the outer query.

Note that you need a similar approach with `GROUP BY`.